# Macbook not going to sleep

Tags: macos, mac, macbook, osx-lion, sleep

My macbook does not want to go to sleep when I close the lid or manually choose sleep from the apple menu.

Things I have tried:

- resetting the PRAM
- resetting the SMC

According to PMSET the following assertion did occur:

```
   PreventSystemSleep                      1
```

No idea why or where that comes from.

Edit: Apparently cupsd is the problem, but why is it acting up all of the sudden? I haven't changed any of my printer settings lately.

Comment: take a look at this:
http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29480/my-macbook-seems-to-be-an-insomniac-wont-sleep
Also, some process could be writing to the disk to prevent sleeping. I had this issue, and could not figure out which process was the culprit, but a restart solved the problem. (not really a solution I know)

Comment: [Related](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3190738?start=0&tstart=0).

Comment: [Related](http://blog.graceabundant.com/archives/2011/08/mac-osx-lion-not-sleeping/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all printers added, re-add them.

Comment: Any chance of an explanation as to why this would fix the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Because printers make requests that prevent your computer from sleeping.

These requests can persist until you uninstall the printer. I had this happen to me for about six months and had no clue at all what it was, but the command (in terminal)

```
pmset -g assertions
```

… showed it was a printer request keeping my computer awake.

Comment: wouldn't purging the print queue help without having to uninstall and install printers? Assuming that there were unfinished print jobs and that's why there were such requests.